# Setting logging level on custom Logger seems to smell

Tags: java, logging

I am using a custom `Logger` for my projects that has some features specifically tailored to the needs of my applications that are not included in the standard logger. It has a simplified structure like this:

```
public enum Logger
{
    INSTANCE;

    public enum MessageType
    {
        TYPE_ERROR,
        TYPE_WARNING,
        TYPE_INFO,
        TYPE_VERBOSE
    }

    // Simplified method...
    public void log(String msg, MessageType level)
    {
        // Handle the message and do something with it...
    }

}
```

I have now implemented a simple method `setLogLevel` to set a logging level, basically define what the user wants to see and what is just going to be logged in the background. Also a short method for checking whether a certain level is going to be logged called `getIsBeingLogged`. Here are the two definitions:

```
private MessageType level = MessageType.TYPE_INFO;

public void setLogLevel(MessageType level)
{
    this.level = level;
}

private boolean isBeingLogged(MessageType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case TYPE_ERROR:
            return true;
        case TYPE_WARNING:
            return this.level == MessageType.TYPE_VERBOSE || this.level == MessageType.TYPE_INFO || this.level == MessageType.TYPE_WARNING;
        case TYPE_INFO:
            return this.level == MessageType.TYPE_VERBOSE || this.level == MessageType.TYPE_INFO;
        case TYPE_VERBOSE:
            return this.level == MessageType.TYPE_VERBOSE;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

The `isBeingLogged` method seems to smell quite badly to me though. If I for example want to add a MessageType `TYPE_DEBUG` that is placed in between `TYPE_INFO` and `TYPE_VERBOSE` in terms of priority I would have to rewrite the whole function and in my opinion it's just asking for a small syntactic error.

---

**Question**

> Is there a more elegant approach to the `getIsBeingLogged`-method and
>   how would I go about it?

I have looked around a bit but could not find a satisfying solution, I hope I haven't overlooked a good solution that is already out there.

Comment: You could "abuse" the enum and always order the types by descending priority and do `return (type.ordinal() <= level.ordinal());`. If you do that, make sure you document the requirement clearly in your enum. But John Kane's answer is better.

Comment: @assylias I did not want to rely on the potential that coworkers change around the ordering because they think alphabetical would look nicer or something like that so I ruled that out. But the idea is really good and John Kane's answer goes in the same direction so thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is any better, but you could set a priority to each log level and return if the priority is above (or below depending on how you set it up) the referenced threshold

Comment: The method now is simply `return level.priority >= type.priority;` which yes, looks way better. And having a simple hidden field `priority` in the message type is not going to hurt. I think this is a good way to go, thanks for the answer!